# JS setTimeout(alert('hi'), 2252124000); overflow!

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Генерирую скрипт под события, но когда временной интервал слишком велик, функция вызывается без задержки. Пример кода:

```
setTimeout(function(){alert('hi')}, 2252124000);
```

Сталкивался ли кто то с данной проблемой? Как можно ее обойти?

Comment: А, кому Вы что собираетесь показывать через 26 суток?

Comment: @Anton_Shcyrov По Вашему не кто не использует "закрепить вкладку"? Или Вы все как мама просила, посидел час выключил комп.

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V, в приведенном коде _alert_ вызывается **до** передачи в setTimeout

Comment: Может разбить `setTimeout` на 1000 кругов с циклом `while`. Или при активации вкладки `$(window).focus(function() {})` в переменную записывать дату/время когда пользователь в нее заходил выделять из него количество дней по сравнению с предыдущей датой/временем, сравнивать с необходимым количеством и потом что-то показывать. И при чем здесь "закрепить вкладку" - они же просто автоматом открываются при запуске браузера а не вечно висят.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, дело в том, что максимальное значение `Signed Integer 32bit` равно `2 147 483 647`, вы вышли за его пределы

Comment: Я тоже так думаю, но я спрашиваю возможно ли это обойти я в JS профан, есть лонг инт или что то еще?

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V, это на уровне движка браузера. Можно например взять исходники, например хромиума, поменять тип соответствующего поля и собрать

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V, проблема на самом деле несколько глубже чем кажется на первый взгляд. Для таких больших интервалов нельзя гарантировать их точное исполнение. для этого как минимум нужно, чтобы страница была **постоянно** активна, в противном случае некоторые браузеры снижают частоту счетчика таймера, в итоге он может сработать намного позже чем ожидалось, даже если использовать трюк с разделением на интервалы длиной 2^31-1